# How to install other distros than precise64 in Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant

Vagrant offers a range of special linux distributions afaik, but the tutorial only names `precise64`, which is Ubuntu Precise 12.04 x64 (and `precise32` is noted somewhere in the deepness of the tutorials).

http://files.vagrantup.com/ contains those vm files, but is not accessable (= gives no folder listing).

**My question: Which other distribution are available, where can i find them and what what are their box names ?**

Comment: Your last three questions appear to be server administration questions. Are you really sure you wouldn't get better answers on ServerFault?

Comment: @PascalCuoq No! StackOverflow is full of good Vagrant threads, and as you can see Vagrant is more for developers, not for ops. And beside that, stop stalking me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a full list of available Vagrant boxes on [www.vagrantbox.es](http://www.vagrantbox.es)

Comment: Nice! **But please note** that most of them must be downloaded from dropboxes and private page etc, so it's not a reliable source. I have a strange feeling when running an operating system that comes from suspicious sources.

Comment: @Panique Agreed. It might be more transparent, maybe keeping some Github repo with installation scripts or something. Anyway, you can still create your own box, if you don't trust them.